# Layouts in java Swing specifying size

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

My question is how can I specify size of the parts on my layout? 
**I need somehow set size of "parts" not using preferedSize, maybe in layout managers, doesn't matter where - only I need is stable size.**

I want to create layout for game. I've already created one but I'm dealing with problem with size of components. So I considered that it would be better to make better concept of my layout. 
Let's look at my draft.

```
+-----------+ 
| UPPER     |
+-----+-----+
|  A  |     |
+-----+  C  |
|  B  |     |
+-----+-----+
| Footer    |
+-----------+

A+B+C make together Center.
```

Main part consist of this tree parts:
Upper- there will be menu. 
Center - this consists of 3 parts A,B,C
Footer - there will be status bar

My idea is to be able to set the size of each component.
All layout is dependent on part C it could have size 450x450 px or 600x600 px.
For part A and B i need specify only the width, because there will be only some text info - it should be about 300 px.
I tryed to use GridBagLayout for Center part but setSize for C didn't worked well.
I make the parts in Containers (java.awt.Container) - in them I add the content of each part and then add the Container to the upper level.

Comment: You should not set the size of components. The components should know their preferred size and return it when getPreferredSize() is called. Most layouts use the preferred size of components to lay them out accordingly.

Comment: Ok I've found out that it's work of layout managers ... I don't want to set preffered size of componet. Can I set strictly the size of component in Layout manager (managers)?

Comment: You can't set the sizes of controls manually, unless you abstain from using a layout manager entirely, and do it *all* manually. I'm afraid there is no middle road.

Comment: I would set the preferred size of `C`, `pack()` the GUI and call `setResizable(false)` on the frame.

Comment: Hi ... I'm struggling with this one myself at present.  I'm at an early stage in my gui, and I'm already having challenges with the main panel which should "expand" to fill the (remaining) available area.  It is annoying.  


I also feel intrinsicly that a "layout" MUST fill the available published space -- Just as the typographical origin of the term is from publishing, the layout is "how the page (as a whole) is layed-out"!

Comment: @will I don't understand the point of your comment ... simply swing layouts are one big useless sh*t. If you have same problem and need layout which work fine and easy then use http://www.miglayout.com/

Comment: Thanks 'user1097772', you are correct; you don't understand the problem.  MigLayout doesn't work with JLayeredPane.  Not mig's fault, it looks like the JLayeredPane isn't doing layers as z-direction panels (looking at source).  If MigLayout did layers; that is the best deal.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way: use BorderLayout for the contentPane (which already is)
  - Upper panel goes to North
  - Footer panel goes to South
  - Panels A and B goes into a Panel ab with GridLayout(2,1)
  - Panel ab and C goes into a Panel abc with GridLayout(1,2)
  - Panel abc goes into the Center
And setPrefferedSize() of your A, B, C

Comment: Sry, but this is not answer to my question ... How can set size of the parts.

Comment: Setting the preferred size of the `C` component is all that is needed (in addition to xyz's overall strategy) to create a logically sized GUI.  If you want to 'pad it out' a little, add borders where needed.  I was going to create a GUI that basically followed the formula outlined by xyz, until a) I saw it had already been said, and b) you claimed it was not what was needed!

Comment: I dissagree, because this cause this cause that the size of `ab` (resp width, heignt is also same but it's not the problem) will be same as the size of `C`. (Setting preffered size also on ab doesnt work too.. ).

Comment: U're right. then u should use GridBagLayout when adding panels ab and C into another panel and of course setPreferredSize of C.

Comment: @xyz When I use GridBagLayout, then stops working the preferedSize at `C` and you can't see only parts of parts A,B,C  ... It's magic circle ...

Answer (score 2):

In general, GridBagLayout ignores the values you set for controls with `setSize`, instead it asks the controls for their *preferred* size (by calling `getPreferredSize`) and uses that for calculating the overall layout. Simply setting that preferred size yourself is not recommended, since most controls tend to recalculate those values whenever a layout is triggered, so you will have a hard time getting them to "stick".

If you really want to make sure the UI element C has a certain size, implement it as a custom class deriving from a suitable base (JPanel, for example) and *override* the `getPreferredSize` method to make it return the size you want/need for that part of your UI.

**Edit:** Here's a little example for a wrapper that can contain another UI element and can be set to a fixed size (using the `setSize` method which has been overridden), which should be respected by layout managers:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FixedSizeComponent extends JPanel {
    private Dimension size;
    private final JComponent content;

    public FixedSizeComponent(JComponent content) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        this.content = content;
        super.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(Dimension d) {
        size = d;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(int width, int height) {
        size = new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getSize() {
        if (size != null) return size;
        return content.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getSize(Dimension rv) {
        if (size != null) {
            if (rv == null) rv = new Dimension();
            rv.height = size.height;
            rv.width = size.width;
            return rv;
        }
        return content.getSize(rv);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (size != null) return size;
        return content.getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        if (size != null) return size;
        return content.getMaximumSize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        if (size != null) return size;
        return content.getMinimumSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, and to make it *really, really* sure, better override the `getMaximumSize` and `getMinimumSize` methods too...

Comment: *"If you really want to make sure the UI element C has a certain size, .. override the getPreferredSize"* Some layout managers will not respect the preferred size.  And I've never understood the advantage of overriding `setPreferredSize()`, when you can simply call it from the constructor and leave it to the developer to choose whether or not the *default* preferred size is the size they want.

Comment: In my experience, the preferred size of controls tends to be recalculated whenever anything invalidates the current layout, so if you just have set it once during construction of the UI, the recalculation will result in your manually set preferred size being overwritten and your carefully arranged layout being wrecked.

Comment: I find that to be highly questionable.  When setting the preferred size of a component (outside either a constructor or overridden method), that preferred size persists no matter what else happens in a GUI (short of another explicit call to `setPreferredSize()` on the component itself).  It might be ignored by the layout, but that is an entirely separate matter.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with a status tool bar at the bottom containing a number of other components. My problem was that it would get taller. So what I did was to override the maximum size setting the maximum height to be the minimum height.

```
JPanel status = new JPanel( new SpringLayout() ) {
  @Override
  public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
    Dimension max = super.getMaximumSize();
    Dimension min = getMinimumSize();
    return new Dimension( max.width, min.height );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is too little and WAY too late,

(maybe this method did not exist at the time of asking of this question)

just like `getPreferredSize`, there is also a `setPreferredSize` method which takes a `Dimension` object.

By default, your layout will ignore your components sizes (which you may have set using `setSize`), instead it will use the preferred sizes.

By using `setPreferredSize`, you will be able to override the default preferred sizes of the component

Answer (score -2):

I hope my answer can help you in some way. From experience with setting JPanel or JFrame size, I have always used `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));`

Comment: Don't get me wrong, using null layout is bad practice; but surely as a last resort, when you are having trouble deciding on the best layout manager to use, and none of them seem to do what you want it to do?

Comment: Null layout is never the answer.

Comment: See [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374)